# Is there an Imagemagick replacement for Photoshop’s “same color” feature?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, imagemagick

Photoshop offers a feature called *same color.* It adjusts the colors of an image based on another.

Here is an example, these 2 pictures share different colors (one of them has an orange shade over it).

**Image 1**

[image: Image 1]

**Image 2**

[image: Image 2]

After using Photoshop‘s *same color* function the first image’s colors are adjusted like this:
[image]

I wonder how you can achieve a similar effect using imagemagick/code or how this effect works in general. Photoshop is able to tell exactly which colors should be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use [histmatch](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/histmatch/index.php) script to accomplish this. Unfortunately the script is hard to get working on a windows machine without cygwin. I am not aware of any other example that would do the same thing.